# multiply a vector and a matrix to create a 3D matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing, dot-product

I have a matrix A of zise MxN, and vector b of size L.
how can I create a matrix C of size MxNxL such that:

C[m, n, k] = A[m, n] * b[k]

pretty much the same as dot product of two vectors to create 2D matrix, but with one dimention higher.

I had tried some variations of a dot product but I couldnt find it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So, not at all like dot product. Dot product usually contain a Σ somewhere. This looks more like a scalar product with some broadcasting.

Comment: I think the fuction you're looking at is outer : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a dot product (sum of the product over an axis), but a simple product that creates a new dimension.

Use broadcasting:

```
C = A[..., None] * b
```

Example:

```
A = np.ones((2,3))
b = np.ones(4)

C = A[..., None] * b

C.shape
# (2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most intuitive way to solve your problem is using `np.einsum`. It follows the maths equation you wrote in the question itself.

```
A = np.ones((2,3))
b = np.ones(4)

C = np.einsum('ij, k -> ijk', A,b)
C.shape
# (2, 3, 4)
```